# How to make a TW3EditBox accept Floating point values

Tags: smart-mobile-studio

When TW3EditBox control's InputType = iNumber, the only public members for controlling the type of Number (Integer vs Float) are:

```
public
 procedure setMin(const aValue: Variant); virtual;
 procedure setMax(const aValue: Variant); virtual;
 procedure setRange(const aValue: Variant); virtual;
```

However, there is nothing for the Step, if one wants to create Edit Boxes that take floating points

e.g.

```
public
 procedure setStep(const aValue: Variant); virtual;
```

How do you do floating point values in edit boxes?

Answer (score -1):

You can set the step like this:

```
w3_setAttrib(NumEdit.Handle, 'step', 0.5);
```